# Related Rates question filling up conical paper cup.

Tags: calculus, related-rates

[image]

So this is just from some college exam and I was trying to do it and got stuck on this question because I've never really encountered related rates before. I read up a bit about related rates but still having some trouble. How would you guys approach this exactly? This is what I was thinking:
Water is poured into the cup at a rate of 4 cubic cm per second so this is telling us $dh/dt = 4$ or $d'(t) = 4$. We're given that the height of the cup is 18cm and the radius of the top is 6 cm. Then the questions ask how fast is the water level rising when the water is 9cm deep? So to me this sounds like $dh/dt$ at $h=9$? Now I'm just not sure how exactly to approach this because I saw some other examples of people solving questions where they just say $r$ is a function of time or something and so they just replace $r$ with $r(t)$ (which makes sense to me) can I just do that? Say $V = (\pi r^2*h)/3$ can I just say that $r = r(t)$ and $h = h(t)$? Or what should I do? I've seen some example videos but didn't really understand any of them too well.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as it doesn't show any work you tried. But, I'd like to give you a kind hint. Do you see that if you draw the cone, the height and radius make a right triangle? And, at every possible water height, r= 1/3 h, therefore you can substitute 1/3 h for r in the volume equation and have an equation relating V and h. differentiate away, my friend.

Comment: @JTP  showing work is not the only legitimate way of adding context.  I think the OP actually elucidated their thought processes, so it is hardly a Problem Statement alone.

Answer (score 2):

Note that at any moment of time $r(t)=h(t)  \frac{6}{18}$. Thus, $V=\frac{1}{27}\pi h^3 $, differentiating by time we come to $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{9} \pi h^2   \frac{dh}{dt}$$
You are also given that $\frac{dV}{dt}=4$ and you need to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$ when $h=9$ so...

Comment: Okay so this is what I'm kinda having trouble understanding so is h a function here..?

Comment: @tommyk: of course, $h$ is changing with time, as well as $r$ and $V$. It's called "related rates" for a reason as there is a relationship between volume growth and the growth of the other two values.

Comment: So here if I have the volume equation (pir^2h)/3 I can just rewrite this as (pir^2(t)*h(t))/3 and they both mean the same thing? Because h and r are functions of time?

Comment: @tommyk: Yes, you have to understand that at any given time the radius and the height are not independent of each other and also that they are changing with time.